# Load existing model into python script in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to animate an existing model I have made in Maya by using a Python script. However, I can't figure out how to access it or its polygons in order to animate them in the script. I know how to select objects beforehand but I just want to write things like this

```
cmds.setKeyframe( objectName, time = startTime, attribute ='rotateY', value = 0 )
```

where objectName is either my entire model or a specific polygon in the model

Comment: Have you tried this with the `-cp` flag set to True?

Comment: No where would I do that?

Comment: basically, loop through your frames, use cmds.move() or similar to move the verts, then call setKeyframe with cp=True to include the vertex changes.  Check the docs for `cmds.setKeyframe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set attribute values inside your setKeyFrame call like you have shown in your code, you will have to set the `attribute` string appropriately. Egs. To set the y transform of a vertex attribute and keyframe it you'd do:

```
objectName = 'pSphere1.vtx[297]'
cmds.setKeyFrame(objectName, attribute='pnty', value=0.7)
# Where 'pnty' stands for Point Y, which is the y transform value for vertices.
```

Another way would be to perform all the transforms before the call to cmds.setKeyFrame() and call it with the controlPoints=True so it catches vertex and control point changes, as @theodox suggested.